# Unable to run Netbeans on OS X El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

As per first image, I'm unable to do anything upon creating a Java Application. Tried it on windows and it's working. How to make netbean work on osx?

I'm not getting any error, I just can't run the new project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the error or prompt you are getting?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh It's a new project, with just main inside and I cant run or compile as per first image shows.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh I reinstalled and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue, Just reinstalled netbeans and the problem will be fixed.